# Mysql stored procedure issue in fetching record

Tags: mysql

I have list of id's in an array. I want to fetch details from table "user" using those id's.

I need a stored procedure where I will send array of id's and will get datails of each id in return array result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try these ways:

- **A:** Use additional table, maybe temporary, to store ID values you need in a procedure, then JOIN this table to another table(s).
- **B:** Pass ID values as a string argument into procedure, then build result SQL statement, and execute it using [MySQL prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

Example (case **A**):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE procedure1()
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM table1 t1 JOIN table_id t2 ON t1.id = t2.id;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

CREATE TABLE table_id(id INT(11));
INSERT INTO table_id VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5);

CALL procedure1();
```

Example (case **B**):

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE procedure1(IN id_param VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
  SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (', id_param, ')');
  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END$$

DELIMITER ;

SET @id = '1,2,3,4,5';
CALL procedure1(@id);
```

Comment: Two example are added)

Comment: i will try both examples